# how to convert 2015-03-25T12:00:00Z date format into Mar 25 2015 12:00:00 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

how to convert  `2015-03-25T12:00:00Z` date format into `Mar 25 2015 12:00:00` in `Javascript`..?

EDITED----
how to convert const Date = "2015-03-25T12:30:45.10112356"; 
 date format into `Mar 25 2015 12:00:00:10112356` in `Javascript`..?

Comment: Can you  solve it in Oracle,sql level and not in javacript?

Comment: How we can solve in oracle level any idea ?

Comment: cleanup the output of `new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00Z").toLocaleString()`, which is the same now in at least firefox and webkit.

Comment: you changed datetime   format of your question in title...  mycomment was related to previous version and for current question you can use momentjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use moment.js for getting the desired format. For the complete list of these formats you can read the docs here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it using moment.js. since I am fresher to js

Comment: from what i gather from your question you can get the desired result using this format("MMM DD YYYY h mm ss")

Comment: Try this code 

const Date = "2015-03-25T12:00:00Z";

const formattedDate=moment(Date).format("MMM DD YYYY h mm ss");

console.log(formattedDate);

Comment: what if I want to manipulate const Date = "2015-03-25T12:30:451012";

Comment: Should work,but If the date is not in ISO recognized format it throws a warning.

Comment: Just checked it is not working for const Date="2015-03-25T12:30:451012". But works fine for const Date= "2015-03-25T12:30:45"

Comment: yeah...I want to show the time in milliseconds.... like--- const Date="2015-03-25T12:30:451012".

Comment: In that case use const Date="2015-03-25T12:30:45.1012"; const formattedDate=moment(Date).format("MMM DD YYYY h mm ss SSSS");

Comment: Notice that you must put a dot between seconds and milliseconds in the Date i.e. use "2015-03-25T12:30:45.1012" instead of "2015-03-25T12:30:451012"

Comment: Hey, I would appreciate if you upvote my answer incase I helped in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00Z"); 
alert(d.toDateString() +" " + d.toTimeString().split(/\s/)[0]);
```

should work in all browsers.